# Exportar lista do sharepoint para json usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

estou utilizando o `sharepoint` e gostaria saber se tem algum jeito de exportar a lista do sharepoint para json, ou seja, fazer um `ajax`

Comment: Olá é possível sim, você pode utilizar a própria API rest ou o Client Object Model para fazer isto com javascript.Veja este link para obter mais informações: https://github.com/andrei-markeev/camljs. Caso você já montou algo publique o seu código

Answer (score 0):

Olá Vc deve criar um HTML assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="RESTGetListItems.js"></script>
<div id="divListItems"></div>
```

E o JavaScript dessa forma:

```
$(function () {
retrieveListItems();});

function retrieveListItems() {var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Demo List')/items?$filter=Id ge 4";
$.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: onQuerySucceeded,
    error: onQueryFailed
});}

function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
var listItemInfo = '';

$.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
    listItemInfo += '<strong>ID: </strong> ' + value.Id +
        ' <strong>Title:</strong> ' + value.Title +
        '<br />';
});

$("#divListItems").html(listItemInfo);}



function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Error!');}
```

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [rest](/questions/tagged/rest)